# How to pass parameter to valueChangeListener in p:dataTable?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, parameter-passing, valuechangelistener

I am calling `valueChangeListener` on a `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>` which is inside a dataTable. and that dataTable is again inside another(outer) dataTable. In the `valueChangeListener` method I want the instance object of outer dataTable. Is there any way to get the object of outer dataTable instance?

EX:

```
<h:panelGroup id="panelId">
    <p:dataTable id="outerDatatable"
                 var="supplier"
                 value="bean.supplierList">

        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Suppliers" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{supplier.name}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column>
            <p:dataTable id="innerDataTable"
                         var="supplierAccount"
                         value="supplier.supplierAccountList">

                <p:column>
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="booleanBoxId"
                                             value="#{supplierAccount.supported}"
                                             valueChangeListener="#bean.checkBoxListener}"
                                             immediate="true"
                                             onchange="this.form.submit();"/>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:panelGroup>
```

I found the following solution : I used `<p:ajax>` listener instead of `valueChangeListener`, and I could pass 'supplier' object as well as `supplierAccount` object to this listener method. We can pass any number of custom objects to `<p:ajax>` listener.

```
<p:column>
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="booleanBoxId"
                             value="#{supplierAccount.supported}"
                             immediate="true">
    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>

    <p:ajax listener="#{bean.myListenerMethod(supplier,supplierAccount)}"
            update=":formName:panelId"/>
</p:column>
```

Answer (score 6):

In this particular case, you could get it by evaluating the `#{supplier}` programmatically:

```
public void checkBoxListener(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Supplier supplier = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{supplier}", Supplier.class);
    // ...
}
```

However, this is plain ugly, you're synchronously submitting the entire form by `onchange="submit()"`. I recommend to throw in some ajax for that.

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{supplierAccount.supported}">
    <f:ajax listener="#{bean.checkBoxListener}" render="???" />
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

*(the `render` attribute is up to you)*

with

```
public void checkBoxListener(AjaxBehavior event) {
    Boolean value = (Boolean) ((UIInput) event.getComponent()).getValue();
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Supplier supplier = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{supplier}", Supplier.class);
    // ...
}
```

Or if your environment supports EL 2.2 and thus specifying method arguments in EL:

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{supplierAccount.supported}">
    <f:ajax listener="#{bean.checkBoxListener(component, supplier)}" render="???" />
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

```
public void checkBoxListener(UISelectBoolean checkbox, Supplier supplier) {
    boolean selected = checkbox.isSelected();
    // ...
}
```

#### See also:

- [When to use valueChangeListener or f:ajax listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879138/when-to-use-valuechangelistener-or-fajax-listener)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, as to using `onchange="submit()"`, it may be useful to know that `onchange` doesn't work as expected for checkboxes in IE6/7. It get only fired on every 2nd click. You rather want to use `onclick="submit()"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you forgot a brace ({) just before `bean`:

```
valueChangeListener="#{bean.checkBoxListener}" immediate="true"
```

Also, since you're using Primefaces, you could use it's components(that if you use version 3): http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/selectBooleanCheckbox.jsf

It isn't necessary to use outputText if you use jsf 2:

```
<f:facet name="header">   
  Suppliers  
</f:facet>
```

Also it isn't necessary to use `f:facet` because the `column` component has an attribute called `headerText`:

```
<p:column headerText="Suppliers">
    #{supplier.name}"
</p:column>
```

It's a lot simpler that way, isn't it?

PS: What's this? `value="supplier.supplierAccountList"` No #{ }?

Comment: thanks for replying.. i newly heard about attribute 'headerText', but i'll have to use <facet>n e ways as its common format used in my project. About value="supplier.supplierAccountList" , its value="#{supplier.supplierAccountList}" only in my code. missed the braces while copying the code here.

Comment: @amruta dialogues like "thanks for ..", "hello .." etc formalities are not received well. infact they are considered spammy.

Comment: @drunkMonk Let the man thank :) At least `hello` is indeed spam