# How to send the currently iterated item to h:selectBooleanCheckbox with f:ajax event=change

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, datatable, valuechangelistener, selectbooleancheckbox

I've the below form:

```
<h:form>
    <h:dataTable value="#{bean.items}" var="item">
        <h:column>
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox  value="#{item.enabled}" valueChangeListener="#{bean.onchangeEnabled}">
                <f:ajax event="change" />
            </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>#{item.name}</h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

I would like to get `#{item}` or at least `#{item.name}` in the value change listener method:

```
public void onchangeEnabled(ValueChangeEvent e) {
    // I would like to get #{item.name} here too.
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can pass it like here http://stackoverflow.com/a/10398023/617373 or here http://stackoverflow.com/a/8385723/617373 or iterate over the `list` and grab the names of *enabled* objects...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, the `valueChangeListener` is the wrong tool for the job. Use `<f:ajax listener>`. Second, `event="change"` is the wrong choice in case of checkboxes/radiobuttons because their physical value actually never changes. You should use `event="click"`, but this is the default already, so you can just omit it.

All in all, the proper initial code should look like this:

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{item.enabled}">
    <f:ajax listener="#{bean.onchangeEnabled}" />
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

with

```
public void onchangeEnabled(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) { // Note: event argument is optional.
    // ...
}
```

Once fixed it like that, then you can easily make use of EL 2.2 capability to pass method arguments:

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{item.enabled}">
    <f:ajax listener="#{bean.onchangeEnabled(item)}" />
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

with

```
public void onchangeEnabled(Item item) {
    // ...
}
```

#### See also:

- [When to use valueChangeListener or f:ajax listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879138/when-to-use-valuechangelistener-or-fajax-listener)
- [What values can I pass to the event attribute of the f:ajax tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886453/what-values-can-i-pass-to-the-event-attribute-of-the-fajax-tag)
- [How can I pass selected row to commandLink inside dataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994458/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-commandlink-inside-a-datatable)
- [Understanding PrimeFaces process/update and JSF f:ajax execute/render attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-primefaces-process-update-and-jsf-fajax-execute-render-attributes)

Comment: Could you elaborate on why event="change" is the wrong choice? He is interested in a value change and not in a mouse click (would event="click" fire when changing the value with the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

For selectBooleanCheckbox it only reacts on the event click and the form should be posted.

so add this to the checkbox

valueChangeListener="#{mybean.myfunction}" onchange="submit();"

it should get fired !